# Angular 2 Observables

Tags: javascript, http, promise, angular, observable

I'm building an app to get some events from facebook, take a look:

EventComponent:

```
events: Object[] = [];

constructor(private eventService: EventService) {
  this.eventService.getAll()
    .subscribe(events => this.events = events)
}
```

EventService:

```
getAll() {
  const accessToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
  const batch = [{...},{...},{...},...];
  const body = `access_token=${accessToken}&batch=${JSON.stringify(batch)}`;

  return this.http.post('https://graph.facebook.com', body)
    .retry(3)
    .map(response => response.json())
}
```

AuthenticationService:

```
getAccessToken() {
    return new Promise((resolve: (response: any) => void, reject: (error: any) => void) => {
      facebookConnectPlugin.getAccessToken(
        token => resolve(token),
        error => reject(error)
      );
    });
  }
```

I have a few questions:

1) How can I set an interval to update the events every 60 seconds?

2) The value of `accessToken` will actually come from a promise, should I do something like this?

```
getAll() {
  const batch = [{...},{...},{...},...];
  this.authenticationService.getAccessToken().then(
    accessToken => {
      const body = `access_token=${accessToken}&batch=${JSON.stringify(batch)}`;
      return this.http.post('https://graph.facebook.com', body)
        .retry(3)
        .map(response => response.json())
    },
    error => {}
  );
}
```

3) If yes, how can I also handle errors from the `getAccessToken()` promise since I'm returning just the Observer?

4) The response from the post request will not return an array of objects by default, I'll have to make some manipulation. Should I do something like this?

```
return this.http.post('https://graph.facebook.com', body)
  .retry(3)
  .map(response => response.json())
  .map(response => {
    const events: Object[] = [];
    // Manipulate response and push to events...
    return events;
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the answers to your questions:

1) You can leverage the `interval` function of observables:

```
getAll() {
  const accessToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
  const batch = [{...},{...},{...},...];
  const body = `access_token=${accessToken}&batch=${JSON.stringify(batch)}`;

  return Observable.interval(60000).flatMap(() => {
    return this.http.post('https://graph.facebook.com', body)
                    .retry(3)
                    .map(response => response.json());
  });
}
```

2) You could leverage at this level the `fromPromise` function of observables:

```
getAll() {
  const batch = [{...},{...},{...},...];
  return Observable.fromPromise(this.authenticationService.getAccessToken())
                   .flatMap(accessToken => {
    const body = `access_token=${accessToken}&batch=${JSON.stringify(batch)}`;
    return this.http.post('https://graph.facebook.com', body)
                    .retry(3)
                    .map(response => response.json())
    });
}
```

3) You can leverage the `catch` operator to handle errors:

```
getAll() {
  const batch = [{...},{...},{...},...];
  return Observable.fromPromise(this.authenticationService.getAccessToken())
                   .catch(() => Observable.of({})) // <-----
                   .flatMap(accessToken => {
    const body = `access_token=${accessToken}&batch=${JSON.stringify(batch)}`;
    return this.http.post('https://graph.facebook.com', body)
                    .retry(3)
                    .map(response => response.json())
    });
}
```

In this case, when an error occurs to get the access token, an empty object is provided to build the POST request.

4) Yes sure! The `map` operator allows you to return what you want...

Comment: For some reason I could not make `fromPromise` work. So to simplify I tried to subscribe only to the `accessToken` but did not work. I place this inside my component constructor: `Observable.fromPromise(this.authenticationService.getAccessToken()).subscribe(response => this.response = response, error => this.response = error);`. I also updated my answer with `getAccessToken()` method.

Comment: I saw that you you use a facebook plugin. Is your problem related to change detection. I mean the data isn't updated in your view... Is the flatMap right after the fromPromise called?

Comment: Yes, I have an [Ionic 2](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/) app using [cordova-plugin-facebook4](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4). Since I couldn't make your code work, I'm trying first to get the `accessToken` based on your answer using observables and show it in my view, after I succeed with it I'll proceed to the post request. I'm not using flatMap() here. When I try to access the page it doesn't load. I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t91encqt/4/) with the relevant part of the code, maybe it will help you understand my trouble.

Comment: Try this import instead: `import {Observable} from '../../node_modules/rxjs/Rx';`

Comment: Damn. You are right, I was importing the `Observable` from the wrong path!! The `accessToken` is ok! Now I'll proceed to the post request.

Comment: Now the observables are ok, but the post request is always returning this error: `{"_body":"","status":404,"statusText":"Ok","headers":{"Client-Via", ["shouldInterceptRequest"]},"type":2,"url":"https://graph.facebook.com/"}`

Comment: i created a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000216/angular-2-http-post-error

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the event inside a timeout block and set the interval of 60s. `setTimeout(() => {},60000)`.
2. Using Template string is totally fine but you're telling its value comes from a promise. If your whole block of code is inside resolve function of promise this should fine. So it depends on where your code is. And why promises .In A2 it's recommended to use Observables and not promises. Don't mix them.
3. You're not returning anything in the error function. So if you return error from that block you'll get error data in case of error. `error => error`or `error => { return error; }`.
4. Exactly you should you map to get the response and manipulate it and return just the array from that function. `.map(resp => { return resp.array})`. Since respons is in JSON format now you have to get array from it and return it. you can do as much modifications you want before returning it.

Feel free to edit the answer...